# Find the commutator $[AX+BY,Z]$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

The problem I'm asked to solve is on quantum mechanics:

> Find the commutator $[xH+pH, p^2]$, where $H$, $x$ and $p$ are the Hamiltonian, space and momentum operator respectively

A the moment, though, I'm stuck on finding the commutator $[AX+BY,Z]$. The correct answer is $A[X,Z]+B[Y,Z]$, though solving it I find:

\begin{align}
[AX+BY,Z] 
& = [AX,Z] + [BY,Z] 
\\ & = A[X,Z] + [A,Z]X + B[Y,Z] + [B,Z]Y
\end{align}

(used the following properties: $[A+B,C]=[A,C]+[B,C]$  and  $[AB,C]=A[B,C]+[A,C]B$)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That identity is wrong, the one you proved is right.

Comment: Note further that $[B,Z]=0$ in your specific case.

Comment: @knzhou But this one is mentioned on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator
I highly doubt it's wrong.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero in my specific case, yes. Still I'm not sure about the identity on the wiki, so I can't be sure about my result on my actual problem.

Comment: @LeshracBanehallow Wikipedia is wrong extremely often, like it is now. Not only is it wrong, it obviously contradicts some correct identities right below it.

Comment: @knzhou Since my solution gives a logical answer  on my actual QM problem, you must be right. I overestimated wikipedia.

Comment: wiki is wrong. what they mean is that A,B are Complex numbers, so basically 5),6) means that the commutator is bilinear. it is unfortunate that in the case 1-4) they use A and B as symbols for operators.

Comment: Usually wikipedia is better, sometimes it helps to crosscheck with the german page (and it is always a bit suspicous if there are not a lot of translationa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity you've derived is correct and the one in Wikipedia is either wrong or it does an insufficient job at explaining the assumptions it makes. (The Wikipedia page has now been flagged as requiring attention from an expert.)

For explicit clarity: if $A,B,X,Y,Z$ are members of a Lie algebra (including, in particular, being operators on a quantum mechanical system, with $[·,·]$ being the commutator), then
\begin{align}
[AX+BY,Z] 
& = [AX,Z] + [BY,Z] 
\\ & = A[X,Z] + [A,Z]X + B[Y,Z] + [B,Z]Y
\end{align}
is correct.